# EFCore Scaffold-DbContext SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-scaffolding

I am using entity framework core to connect to my existing SQL DB that is used by other applications as well and therefor want to use the scaffolding to create my models from said DB.
I have used it time and time again to create my models from the existing DB but this time I am getting this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'has_filter'.
> Invalid column name 'filter_definition'.

The command I am running is trying to load just one view that does not contain any of the columns mentioned in the error.

The command I am running in the Package Manager Console is:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -connection "Data Source=DBSRV;Initial Catalog=DB;User ID=usr;Password=psw" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -Project "LibProject" -OutputDir Models -Tables "VIEW" -force
```

The error is thrown only when I try to use the scaffolding on this DB, if I use it in other DBs it works flawlessly.

Why am I getting this error? Can someone point me at what I need to check to fix this?

Comment: What Server version and what is the compatibility level of your database?

Comment: And which EF Core version?

Comment: sorry for the delay the compability level of this specific DB is SQL Server 2005 (90) and the EF Core version is 3.1.8

Comment: This is a bug for EF, SQL Server 2008 fixed this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error on EF Core 6 connecting to SQL Server 2005. Then I found that is a version compatibility issue.

According to Microsoft documentation you need at least SQL Server 2012 for EF Core 6 or 7:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/